# DNN Friendly URL Regular Expression

Tags: url, e-commerce, dotnetnuke

Just want to seek some help to make my URL better:

**This is my original URL:**

https://www.wilcom.com/Hatch/Products/HotcakeStoreAdmin/ProductViewer/tabid/3605/slug/Embroidery-Basics/Default.aspx

**This is the URL after Advanced DNN Friendly URL Setting:**

https://www.wilcom.com/Hatch/Products/Hotcake-Store-Admin/Product-Viewer/Embroidery-Basics

**How do I make it even shorter in the Friendly URL setting?**

I want to remove "Products", "Hotcake-Store-Admin" and "Product-Viewer" from the above URL.

Thanks if anyone can help me with it...

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown of what is likely building out your URL to be what it is currently.

[image: URL formatting breakdown]

To shorten your URL, you'll need to restructure the pages on your site, and/or change the name of the page in the respective page settings for the pages where the URL doesn't meet your standards.

You'll see two other images below that outline how to get to the page settings and the URL setting specifically.  Your URL will first be based upon the site's page structure (or information architecture) when you add your pages.  Second, it will be determined by the setting you apply in the image named "step-01".

[image: Step One: Go to Page Settings]

[image: Step Two: Update the URL]

Please review the images and make your changes as you desire to meet your URL requirements.